# How to get a high resolution image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

My problem is, when I take a picture from camera and passing to another activity. The image is not in high resolution. How can I make my image in high resolution. My code is below:

Main Activity

```java
Button btn_cam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cam);
btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

    }
});
```

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Intent cam = new Intent(this, MainCam.class);
        cam.putExtra("flostic", image);
        startActivity(cam);
}
```

Second Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
imageBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("flostic");
```

Comment: you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, the docs say: *"If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field"*

Comment: but actually you have asked the same question 3 times already: each time you were told to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, so how many times do you want to repeat that question again and again?

Comment: yea. but only a Bitmap object can run in my application

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that

Answer (score 1):

Add an `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` to the intent,and give path in `putExtra` to specify path for picture saving, because otherwise it only returns a snap of picture not a high resuolution picture. Refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

Standard `Intent` action that can be sent to have the camera application capture an image and return it. The caller may pass an extra `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the `Uri` value of `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.